# How to print the tree with height?

Tags: c#

I have the following code that fills a binary tree (not BST)

How do i get the height of the tree and print it along with its height?

```
int[] values = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(values);

class BinaryTree
{
    int value;
    BinaryTree left;
    BinaryTree right;

    public BinaryTree(int[] values) : this(values, 0) {}

    BinaryTree(int[] values, int index)
    {
        Load(this, values, index);
    }

    void Load(BinaryTree tree, int[] values, int index)
    {
        this.value = values[index];
        if (index * 2 + 1 < values.Length)
        {
            this.left = new BinaryTree(values, index * 2 + 1);
        }
        if (index * 2 + 2 < values.Length)
        {
            this.right = new BinaryTree(values, index * 2 + 2);
        }
    }
    int getDepth()
    {
      //code to get height here
    }
}
```

..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to travel all the nodes and check for the height;

```
   depth = 1 + max(left.depth, right.depth)
```

You need to check for null, anyway.

C# code:

```
   return 1 + Math.Max(left?.getDepth() ?? 0, right?.getDepth() ?? 0)
```

Comment: do i simply insert that in the getDepth() function?

Comment: No, you need to figure out how to check for null in case left or right is null.

Comment: so like this: `    int getDepth(int index)
    {
         if (index == NULL)
         return 0; return 1 + max(left?.getDepth() ?? 0, right?.getDepth() ?? 0)
    }`

Comment: @debracey i assure you, its not a HW at all. im already finished with school a year ago, im just in the phase of learning C# cause i mainly come from powershell, if you look at all my previous posts :)

Comment: No. Dan's answer is correct as is. The idea is to get the depth of the whole tree, so you get the max depth of {left, right} and then add 1 for the root of the portion of the tree you're interrogating. The idea is to solve the problem with recursion.

Comment: @debracey i see. what does the ?? double question marks indicate?

Comment: @DanielTran used some advanced syntax there. It can be read as "If {left} is not null, call getDepth and get the return value; otherwise use 0". The ?? is the null-coalescing operator. ?. is the null conditional (sometimes called "Elvis") operator

Comment: @debracey i see, thank you. question, since i followed some guides online on the mathematical part of forming the binary tree, i didnt really understand what the multiplication is for. index * 2 ... can you explain to me briefly why is the multiplication happening? is it to go onto the second level? i think i know what the + is for, since we start the array at 0. if we started it on 1, the left equation would be index * 2 and the right one would be index * 2 + 1. but i dont really understand how this evaluation comes to be

Comment: is it correct if i modify the code in my post to define left and right this way? BinaryTree left, right;

Comment: @Cataster either syntax will work, but i think the way you have it is preferred, since it is easier to read at a quick glance. I don't usually see the , operator in declarations.

Comment: @debracey gotcha, thanks! not sure if you seen my earlier message, but is there a straightforward explanation (no mathemeatical breakdown) of how the left and right childs are determined? i.e. why index * 2 + 1? why multiply by 2? i know it has to do with powers of 2 but why/how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197643/discussion-between-debracey-and-cataster).